# Icons of external devices not appearing on desktop

Tags: icons, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a USB drive shortcut on desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194705/how-do-i-get-a-usb-drive-shortcut-on-desktop)

In 10.04 and all, when a pen drive or as for that matter, when any external devices are connected, their icons are shown on the desktop and nautilus pops up automatically too. But in my 12.04 Gnome classic, when I connect an external device, nothing happens. I have to open nautilus manually and then click on the icon in the left panel to access the folder of the device.

Is there any way to rectify this and restore the old trait as in 10.04?