# How do I get a USB drive shortcut on desktop?

Tags: usb-drive, shortcuts

Is there a flash drive shortcut on Ubuntu 12.04 desktop like Ubuntu 10.10 desktop have?

[image: USB shortcut on Desktop]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and execute the command below:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible true
```

This will enable the feature in 12.04. Here is a screenshot from 12.04 Desktop:

[image: Cropped flash drive desktop shortcut]

Answer (score 3):

1. Install [gnome-tweak-tool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-tweak-tool) [image: Install gnome-tweak-tool]
2. Run it by keying <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `gnome-tweak-tool`
3. Then go to the Desktop tab and turn on "Have file manager handle the desktop", and "Show mounted volumes on the desktop".

Comment: An awesome reply sir! This worked wonderfully! :)