# USB devices do not appear in desktop or launcher (not automounted)

Tags: 12.04, unity, usb, launcher, automount

After a recent upgrade, the USB devices are not appearing in desktop or launcher.

- When plugged in, devices power up. `lsusb` shows this output,

> ```
> <truncated>
> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 174c:5106 ASMedia Technology Inc. Transcend StoreJet 25M3
> Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0411:0098 BUFFALO INC. (formerly MelCo., Inc.)
> ```

Last two are the devices I have plugged in.

- The devices are not found in `ls /media/`
- I have tried the solution using `myunity` as indicated in https://askubuntu.com/a/101415/82650. Turned on `Show Devices`, no luck.
- I have also tried executing `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible true` as elaborated in [How do I get a USB drive shortcut on desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194705/how-do-i-get-a-usb-drive-shortcut-on-desktop). Again no luck, the devices do not appear in desktop.
- **[EDIT]** Looked in to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB. Checked my machine in `dconf-editor`. The `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling` key for automount has been properly set.
- **[EDIT]** The devices are recognized both in [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) and [Disk Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks). All the device information shown are completely correct. The devices are present as /dev/sdd1 and /dev/sde1. But amazingly both Gparted and Disk Utility are showing that the devices are *not* mounted.
- **[EDIT]** If I manually mount the devices using the command  `sudo mount device (/dev/sdd1 or /dev/sde1 <to some dir>` this works fine. I can access the devices from all applications.

So, the problem boils down to, the devices *are not being auto mounted*.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (home machine). This is where the problem occurs. The devices work fine (automount) in my office machine, Ubuntu 13.04.

**[EDIT 2]**: After installation of `autofs` and `automount` and a reboot of the machine, the devices are being automounted again.

Still, I would like to know,

1. Why do I have to install these? How did they get uninstalled?
2. How did the devices work fine so far?

Comment: Are the devices present under `/dev/`? They only show up in `/media/` if they are mounted. And also check with `Disk Utility` or `Gparted` if the OS recognizes the USB devices.

Comment: @JoãoAndré The devices are recognized both in `Gparted` and `Disk Utility` (Why the command is `palimsest`? Had to spend some time to find it out. :-)). All the device information shown are completely correct. The devices are present as `/dev/sdd1` and `/dev/sde1`. But amazingly both `Gparted` and `Disk Utility` are showing that the devices are not mounted. So, the problem boils down to, the devices are not being mounted.

Comment: @JoãoAndré Please see the edits in my original post.

Comment: Seems like you solved the problem at your second edit. Regarding 1) those packages aren't installed by default, so they didn't get "uninstalled". I'd guess there were some problems with the 12.04 kernel and those specific USB drives, that have been fixed in recent versions. As for 2), a device not being mounted doesn't mean he should not be functioning correctly, it just isn't being used by the OS. The problem was with the OS and not the devices, so they would work fine in any other computer or OS.